# create cookie when user will open page second time wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

Here is my code:

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('domain_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, '/', 'domain.com', false);
    } 
} 
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

With this code cookie works well but when am checking cookie existance via this javascript code (need to check whether we have cookie or not to use it somewhere else in javascript code):

```
var isCookie = document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?domain_newvisitor=[^;]+(.*)?$/);
if(isCookie){
     console.log('yes');
}else{
     console.log('no');
}
```

it always shows 'yes' in console log, even when am deleting cookie and visiting website first time. How can I change php code to create cookie only when user will open page second time.

Comment: Just want to know are you running second piece of after the first code each time?

Comment: Shouldn't it be other way Check if the cookie doesn't exists then create else leave it?

Comment: Log `isCookie` to console, to see what it is/contains in each case.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean "leave it" ? You mean this <?php else{setcookie('domain_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, '/', 'domain.com', false);}?> ? @A.J

Comment: I did how you said, for this cookie 'domain_newvisitor' it is same. both first time and second time it exists @CBroe

Comment: @aidaghazaryan : By leave it i meant don't set cookie as it is already there.

Comment: @A.J that cookie sets via my php code above and if I remove that setcookie code I won't have that cookie anymore. Can you show me some code what you mean pls ?

Comment: @aidaghazaryan :  I have posted an answer. Read if it makes things clear. You can use $CookieValue  in js by passing it from server to js.

Comment: @aidaghazaryan :  Did you go through the answer? Did it solve your problem or showed you why it was not workling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97190/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-a-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the cookie as:

```
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie('domain_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, '/', 'domain.com', false);
    } 
} 
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

Explanation: If the cookie is set already => `!isset($_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor'])` and user is not admin you are setting cookie.

---

After this it is being checked it the cookie exits :

```
var isCookie = document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?domain_newvisitor=[^;]+(.*)?$/);
if(isCookie){
     console.log('yes');
}else{
     console.log('no');
}
```

Then the cookie will exits every time. As you are creating it if it is first time and checking if it exits.

---

You should check if cookie exits then store it variable and use it of not then create it:

```
 function set_newuser_cookie() {
        if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor'])) {
            setcookie('domain_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*100, '/', 'domain.com', false);
        }else
        if(!is_admin() && isset($_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor'])){
             $CookieValue = $_COOKIE['domain_newvisitor']
             //echo or return this $CookieValue 
        } 
    }


add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

Now You can use $CookieValue in js by passing it from server to client.